# Pass variable from batch to html input value

Tags: html, batch-file

I need to pass a variable from batch file to html input value

If I set a %variable% to the html input value it return %variable% but not the real value of it...

My code :

```
<!-- :
:: textSubmitter.bat
@echo off

set "location=bob"



for /f "tokens=1-8 delims=," %%a in ('mshta.exe "%~f0"') do (
    set "dossier=%%a"
    set "occupation=%%b"
    set "lieu=%%c"
    set "dated=%%d"
    set "datef=%%e"
    set "ets=%%f"
    set "type=%%g"
    set "subdi=%%h"
)

    echo "Dossier =%dossier%"
    echo "Occupation =%occupation%"
    echo "Lieu :=%lieu%"
    echo "Date Debut : =%dated%"
    echo "Date Fin : =%datef%"
    echo "Entreprise : =%ets%"
    echo "Type : =%type%"
    echo "Subdi : =%subdi%"

pause
goto :EOF

-->

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Classement chantier</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script language='javascript' >
        function pipeText() {
            var dossier=document.getElementById('dossier').value;
            var occupation=document.getElementById('occupation').value;
            var lieu=document.getElementById('lieu').value;
            var dated=document.getElementById('dated').value;
            var datef=document.getElementById('datef').value;
            var ets=document.getElementById('ets').value;
            var type=document.getElementById('type').value;
            var subdi=document.getElementById('subdi').value;

            var Batch = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1);
            close(Batch.WriteLine(dossier+','+occupation+','+lieu+','+dated+','+datef+','+ets+','+type+','+subdi));
      }
    </script>

    Dossier : <input type='text' name='dossier' size='25' value='%location%'></input><br>
    Occupation : <input type='text' name='occupation' size='25'></input><br>
    Lieu : <input type='text' name='lieu' size='25'></input><br>
    Date Debut : <input type='text' name='dated' size='25'></input><br>
    Date Fin : <input type='text' name='datef' size='25'></input><br>
    Entreprise : <input type='text' name='ets' size='25'></input><br>
    Type : <input type='text' name='type' size='25'></input><br>
    Subdi : <input type='text' name='subdi' size='25'></input><br>

    <hr>
    <button onclick='pipeText()'>Submit</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the html form the variable "%location%" should return the value "bob" but it return "%location%"

`<input type='text' name='dossier' size='25' value='%location%'>`

Please how to set the batch variable to the html input value to get the value "bob" ?

Comment: The double quotes both sides of the variable set is completely wrong. You did it right every where else so why different there? `set "location=bob"`

Comment: It's a typo, I added this example to explain the issue...